# OsmDroid load Marker after scroll

Tags: android, osmdroid

I want to load Marker after scroll. In Google Maps I user OnCameraChange, in OsmDroid I used OnScroll, but is called always until I move the map. How can I detect when the scroll is ended as OnCameraChange ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean `after scroll`

- current visible part of the map has changed
- that scroll/zoom including animatation has finished
- there were no scroll/zoom for the last 200 millisecs

you can try to add a `DelayedMapListener` as a map listener that fires 200 millisecs after the last scrolling/zooming

```
/** Fire if there is more than 200 millisecs no zoom/scroll update markers */
protected static final int DEFAULT_INACTIVITY_DELAY_IN_MILLISECS = 200;

    // If there is more than 200 millisecs no zoom/scroll update markers
    mMapView.setMapListener(new DelayedMapListener(new MapListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
            reloadMarker();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onZoom(ZoomEvent event) {
            reloadMarker();
            return false;
        }
    }, DEFAULT_INACTIVITY_DELAY_IN_MILLISECS));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OSMmap.setMapListener(new DelayedMapListener(new MapListener() {

        public boolean onZoom(final ZoomEvent e) {
            reloadMarker();
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onScroll(final ScrollEvent e) {
        reloadMarker();
        return true;
       }
}, 1000 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correct, it isn't natively supported with osmdroid (onScrollEnd basically). Is that right? You want an event at the end of scrolling?

On Scroll is only fired when the map is in the process of panning. If you're experiencing different behavior, it's probably a bug. In fact, something similar was reported not too long ago. It should be fixed in 5.2 or newer of osmdroid

To fire after a scroll has finished, I'd suggest tracking the time of the last onScroll event, then in a background thread periodically checking the timestamp of the last event.

The other option is to extend the `org.osmdroid.views.overlay.DefaultOverlayManager` and override whatever keypress or touch events you want.

You can then attach your custom overlay manager to the mapview with this
`mapView.setOverlayManager(yourManager);`